# Proper use of 'there' and 'here' in phrase

Tags: word-choice

I am thanking someone in type 
by saying :

> "John and Mary for being **there** even when you aren't near."

Would it be better or worse to use 'here' :

> "John and Mary for being **here** even when you aren't near."

Comment: You probably want to say "Thanks to John and Mary for *being there **for me***, even when they aren't near", though "being there" would serve as a perfectly fine abbreviation of that phrase, and "being here" a amusing and comprehensible pun.

Answer (score 1):

In context of the statement, it appears that you wish to express gratitude for their presence. (evident from : aren't near)

"John and Mary for their (reassuring) **presence** even when you aren't **near**."

A look at these examples:

■I want you to come **here** to see me.

■I am already **here** so let me see if they have to stuff I need.

■I called my friend to tell her that I am **here**.

Here-*has been used when something or someone is close*.

"John and Mary for being **here** even when you aren't near."

Another example, here vs there:

David: Is there an apple on that table over there?

Frank: Yes, there is. Here it is.

David: Great, are there any oranges?

Frank: No, there aren't.

David: Oh, here they are, next to me on this table.