# 'there' vs 'here on phone call

Tags: word-choice

I'm on phone call between multiple participants. Initiator asks:

-Who is on the call?

What is correct form to answer? "John Doe is **there**" or "John Doe is **here**"?

From other question ([Proper use of 'there' and 'here' in phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196957/proper-use-of-there-and-here-in-phrase/196965?s=1|0.2722#196965)) I can see a rule "*Here-has been used when something or someone is close.*" - is it applicable to phone call, so **here** should be used?

Comment: Which end of the conversation are you on?  If John is with you in the room you'd say he's here.  If John is in the room at the other end of the line you'd say he's there.  Just as if you were in a large room and John were either standing beside you or standing on the the other side of the room.

Comment: In a conference call, don't use *here* or *there*. Just identify yourself. When calling someone else directly, use "here" because "here" is where you are: "Hi, Mabel. John here."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Here" implies the location of whoever said it, but it's sensitive to the context in which it is used.

If you said "John is here", others would assume he's standing next to you.
On the other hand, if you said "John is here with us", they would assume he's in on the call (his location isn't relevant, only that he's listening in and able to respond)

If John introduced himself or identified himself during a group call, he'd say "John here, I have a question:"

The latter seems to be carried over from when people identify themselves when talking in large groups. It's not really a location-based "here", more a saying that's so common it'd be awkward to phrase it differently.